# c++ intermidiate result - undefined behaviour

Tags: c++

Recently while working on my project, i learned about intermidiate result. So basically it means that if int * int then the result is int. So my original code was-
[Original Code- Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNR7w.png)

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
unsigned int x,y,xy,x2,y2,n;
long int t1,t2,t;
x=59160;
y=7560;
xy=8185320;
x2=86305600;
y2=1139984;
n=51;
t=((n * x2) - (x * x))*((n * y2) - (y * y));
std::cout << "t=" << t << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Output-"t=1107970048"- which is wrong

Now as expected, there was an overflow in expression n*x2 and i fixed it by changing the n & x2 variables to long int. Later i tried this code (see image below) and it worked-

[Modified code- correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNR7w.png)

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
unsigned int x,y,xy,x2,y2,n;
long int t1,t2,t;
x=59160;
y=7560;
xy=8185320;
x2=86305600;
y2=1139984;
n=51;
t1=(n * x2) - (x * x);
t2=(n * y2) - (y * y);
t=t1*t2;
std::cout << "t=" << t << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Output-"t=888681381120000"- which is correct

My question is, why the expression n*x2 is not causing overflow in the above program.
Compiled using g++ 7.3

Comment: Please share your code as actual code and not images, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) on meta for why.

Comment: Sorry, i have modified my question as you said.

Comment: Why there should be an overflow? Resulting value fits into 32-bit unsigned integer. And how do you think overflow should manifest itself?

Comment: Both code snippets are the same!?

Comment: Because 51*86305600=4401585600 while unsigned int can hold a maximum value of 4294967295. If i try this expression-
unsigned int n=51,x2=86305600;
long int t=n*x2;
Then it overflows

Comment: @Flopp , sorry. Somehow i pasted same code twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a double overflow in `(n * x2) - (x * x)`!

(1) `n * x2` overflows to `106618304` (since the correct result `4401585600` doesn't fint into an `unsigned int`).

(2) Then you have:
`106618304 - 3499905600`.
Again, the correct result `-3393287296` doesn't fit into an `unsigned int`, and thus overflows to `901680000`.

Funny enough, `901680000` would have been the correct result if no overflows have been occured at all (e.g. if all variables were of type `long int`).

Please note that overflow of `unsigned int` is *not* undefined behaviour -  it's perfectly defined. `signed int` overflow is undefined!

Comment: Thanx alot @Flopp , i never thought this way :-p . By the way can you tell me how to calculate overflow value when storing negative & out of range values (Example -3499905600) in an unsigned int without programatically solving it?